How to convert an mp4 file to mp3 using FFMpegCore?
How can I convert an mp4 video to mp3, using the nuget-package FFMpegCore in a C# Project (.NET 8)?
public void ConvertViaFFMpegCore(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
{
    FFMpegArguments
        .FromFileInput(sourcePath)
        .OutputToFile(targetPath, false, options => options
            .WithVideoCodec(VideoCodec.???) // <- ???
            .WithConstantRateFactor(21)
            .WithAudioCodec(AudioCodec.???) // <- ???
            .WithVariableBitrate(4)
            .WithVideoFilters(filterOptions => filterOptions
                .Scale(VideoSize.Hd))
            .WithFastStart())
        .ProcessSynchronously();
}


So as mp3 is just an audio format, you want to extract the audio from the mp4 video?

There is a method for extracting audio.
string inputFile = @"path-to-input.mp4";
string outputFile = @"path-to-output.mp3";

FFMpegCore.FFMpeg.ExtractAudio(inputFile, outputFile);

Note, this does require the main ffmpeg.exe to be in the project output directory.

Unfortunately, I get the following error, when executing FFMpeg.ExtractAudio(x, y); "Output file does not contain any stream
Error opening output file [...]
Error opening output files: Invalid argument"

Are you able to share your paths? Are they valid, do the directories exist? Are they free of invalid characters etc?
